# What is a random class rotation in a few shot learning task?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I was seeing this:

```
def get_remaining_transforms_omniglot(dataset: MetaDataset, ways: int, shots: int) -> list[TaskTransform]:
    """

    Q: todo, what does RandomClassRotation do? https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/372
    """
    import learn2learn as l2l
    remaining_task_transforms = [
        l2l.data.transforms.FusedNWaysKShots(dataset, ways, shots),
        l2l.data.transforms.LoadData(dataset),
        l2l.data.transforms.RemapLabels(dataset),
        l2l.data.transforms.ConsecutiveLabels(dataset),
        l2l.vision.transforms.RandomClassRotation(dataset, [0.0, 90.0, 180.0, 270.0])
    ]
    return remaining_task_transforms
```

and was wondering:

1. what does it? does it do to the classes i.e. labels
2. what does it do to the images?

ref: https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/372

Answer (score 3):

Based on a read of the `class RandomClassRotation` which you have linked, this is a random rotation transformation where every image from the same class has the same rotation. E.g. all cats are will have a 90 degree rotation, and all dogs will have a 270 degree rotation.

There is no change to the labels.